# Using a Scala's value class from Java

Tags: scala, value-class

I'm using value class in Scala to avoid boxing at runtime.

Eg.:

```
trait Service {
  def getThing(thingId: ThingId): Thing
}

final case class ThingId(value: Long) extends AnyVal
```

However, I'm using that same value class from Java code:

```
interface JavaService {
    Thing getThing(ThingId thingId);
}
```

This does not work since `ThingId` is actually compiled as a Long:

```
JavaService.java:[2,19] error: 
  incompatible types: ThingId cannot be converted to long
```

Is there a pattern to use value classes (or any wrapper/helper that would help) from Java?

Comment: The initial question was not (this one is a "how" and the other one is a "why")... the the comments of the other one actually seem to answer that question: there is no elegant pattern.

Comment: Indeed, there is no elegant way to do this since this is an optimization in Scala land. All the JVM sees is the underlying type (hopefully, if you follow the `AnyVal` pattern correctly).